# Vue + Laravel in Heroku

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to upload my Laravel+Vue.js on Heroku, but the components do not appear, only the blades

I did the following steps:

- `git init`
- `echo "web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/" > Procfile`
- `heroku create`
- `heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs`
- `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`
- `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "npm run prod"
}
```

- `heroku config:set APP_KEY=”My app key”`
- `git push heroku master`

Comment: It's better to ask in English here :)